# Pinging from a C/C++ program

Tags: c++, c, network-programming, ping

I want to write a C or C++ program, that given an IP address, Pings it and then performs further action based on whether the Ping was successful or not.
How to do this?

Comment: Depending on what you want to accomplish, the nmap sources may be interesting to look through.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189935/is-there-any-way-to-ping-a-specific-ip-address-with-c/23071412#23071412

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have a blast at [The Ping Page](http://www.ping127001.com/pingpage.htm), which has a link to [full source](http://www.ping127001.com/pingpage/ping.text) on the original Unix [`ping(8)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ping).

Comment: Thanks! It has a lot of legacy code that makes it not work properly with modern C compilers. Is there an updated source code for ping?

Answer (score 19):

**EDIT**   I saw after I posted, you are on Ubuntu. However someone searching this question may still find these links helpful for Windows.

Ping: Raw Sockets Method: http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/examples/rawping.html

Implementing Internet Pings Using Icmp.dll: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;170591

IcmpSendEcho Function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366050%28VS.85%29.aspx

Ping for Windows: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/winping.aspx

Answer (score 5):

This post is old but I think the following link will help future people lookign for a good explanation on how to create a Ping request.

- [Deconstructing Ping with C and NodeJS](https://github.com/davidgatti/Deconstructing-Ping-with-C-and-NodeJS)

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int x = system("ping -c1 -s1 8.8.8.8  > /dev/null 2>&1");
if (x==0){
    cout<<"success";
}else{
    cout<<"failed";
}
```

replace 8.8.8.8 from your IP Address