# Is there any way to ping a specific IP address with C?

Tags: c, networking, ip-address

Is there any way to ping a specific IP address with C?
If I wanted to ping "www.google.com" with a certain number of pings, or for that matter, a local address, I would need a program to do that. How can I ping from C?

Comment: Use the `socket` API (`man socket`).

Comment: Why would you want to ping Google, assuming you don't work for Google?

Comment: It is operating system specific. And `www.google.com` is not an IP address (but `192.168.2.34` is one).

Comment: @dbasnett you really can't think of any possible reason?

Comment: @BrennanVincent - unless I am a network person, no I can't. If you are a programmer and just want to know with some certainty that your network is functional then pinging your local gateway should be sufficient.

Comment: How do you know if your  local gateway is actually hooked up to the internet?

Answer (score 12):

There is no accepted answer yet and I stumbled upon this question while trying to do exactly what was asked here so I wanted to refer to [Aif's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51760/aif) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7292659/2123539).

The following code is based on his example and pings Google's public DNS in a child process and prints the output in the parent process.

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFLEN 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int pipe_arr[2];
    char buf[BUFLEN];

    //Create pipe - pipe_arr[0] is "reading end", pipe_arr[1] is "writing end"
    pipe(pipe_arr);

    if(fork() == 0) //child
    {
        dup2(pipe_arr[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        execl("/sbin/ping", "ping", "-c 1", "8.8.8.8", (char*)NULL);    
    }
    else //parent
    {
        wait(NULL);
        read(pipe_arr[0], buf, BUFLEN);
        printf("%s\n", buf);

    }

    close(pipe_arr[0]);
    close(pipe_arr[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The execl() command has an incorrect parameter. The parameter "-c 1" should be written as "-c", "1".

Answer (score 11):

You could craft your own [ICMP packets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) using [raw sockets](http://mixter.void.ru/rawip.html), but that's far from trivial.  The [source code for `ping(1)`](http://www.skbuff.net/iputils/) is a good place to start on figuring out how to do that (it uses a BSD-like license; see the source code for the full license).  Keep in mind that raw sockets require root privileges on Linux, so your program will need to be setuid root.

Of course, it's much easier to shell out to the `ping(1)` executable and not have to deal with any of this yourself.  You won't have to worry about code licensing, and your program won't need root privileges (assuming it doesn't already need them for something else).  [`system(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system), [`popen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen), and [`fork(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork)/[`exec(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) are your friends.

Comment: I wish you have given a better explanation of the system/exec ping method.  This would have been extremely helpful.

Comment: The raw sockets link is dead :/

Answer (score 3):

You would have to learn sockets, resolve the host you want to ping, send the appropiate ICMP packages and listen for a response. There is no `ping` function in the standard library. However, there are lots of higher level network libraries that already implement the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the simplest I found.

http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~cop4600/cgi-bin/lxr/http/source.cgi/commands/simple/ping.c

Comment: How would I locate the net/gen files? They seem to be in unavailable when I try and compile!

Comment: The answer when I try to use your link : 403 Forbidden

Comment: The answer is from 2011!?